# Display the counted results of rows in a MySQL database and display it in ChartJs

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, ajax

I want to display the recorded number of rows in MySQL Database and display the numbers in ChartJs but it seems that the numbers are not displaying properly from what I got from my PHP Script.

**PHP Snippet Code for Counting Records from MySQL Database (Users_Retrieval.php)**

```
$JSON_Response = array();

//Counts the number of Reporters
$Reporter_Query = "SELECT User_ID FROM User WHERE User_Type = 0";
$Count_Reporter = mysqli_query($Connection, $Reporter_Query);

$Reporter_Total = mysqli_num_rows($Count_Reporter);
array_push($JSON_Response, $Reporter_Total);

//Counts the number of Firefighters
$Firefighter_Query = "SELECT User_ID FROM User WHERE User_Type = 1";
$Count_Firefighter = mysqli_query($Connection, $Firefighter_Query);

$Firefighter_Total = mysqli_num_rows($Count_Firefighter);
array_push($JSON_Response, $Firefighter_Total);

echo json_encode($JSON_Response);
```

> When I print the contents of the json_encode it prints the values of what I expected and I think there's no problem in my PHP script.
>   **Output of json_encode: [5,1]**

**JavaScript ChartJs Code**

```
//Reporter_Result and Firefighter_Result is both initialized in 1. It will 
//be changed once the retrieval of JSON is correct
var Reporter_Result = 1; 
var Firefighter_Result = 1;
$.ajax({
        url: "Users.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(response){
            //alert(response);
            var User = JSON.parse(response);
            var Reporter_Result = text(User.reporter);
            var Firefighter_Result = text(User.firefighter);
        }
    });

var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["Reporters", "Firefighters"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [Reporter_Result, Firefighter_Result],
      backgroundColor: ['#007bff', '#dc3545'],
    }],
  },
});
```

> I think the problem is in my javascript file, It does not received the values from my **Users_Retrieval.php** which is **[5,1]** properly (my theory) and the way I'm trying to access the JSON values in my javascript.

Here's my current progress / output of pie chart where I will plug the results:

[image]

**Question/s:**

> How do I get the values from JSON in my Users_Retrieval.php? Is my implementation of receiving the JSON values in my javascript is wrong? How do I get them properly in order to plug the values in my Pie Chart?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it was me, I'd be tempted to start here:

```
SELECT User_Type
     , COUNT(*) total
  FROM User
 GROUP 
    BY User_Type;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue I'm seeing here is this:

```
var Reporter_Result = text(User.reporter);
var Firefighter_Result = text(User.firefighter);
```

you appear to be referencing named values but in your php code (and output) you are using an ordered array.

you can either define `$JSON_Response` as a key-value array before your `json_encode` like so:

```
//array_push($JSON_Response, $Reporter_Total); // not like this
$JSON_Response['reporter'] = $Reporter_Total;
```

and then your js will work

** **OR** ** change the js to something like:

```
 //var Reporter_Result = text(User.reporter); // not like this
 var Reporter_Result = text(User[0]);
```

---EDIT

just saw something much more problematic - you are fetching the results via AJAX but you create the pie chart linearly - so the value of (example) `Firefighter_Result` is the default 1 once the chart plotting starts

try changing your code to this:

```
var myPieChart;
$.ajax({
    url: "Users.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(response){
        //alert(response);
        var User = JSON.parse(response);
        var Reporter_Result = text(User.reporter);
        var Firefighter_Result = text(User.firefighter);


        myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
           type: 'pie',
           data: {
               labels: ["Reporters", "Firefighters"],
               datasets: [{
                 data: [Reporter_Result, Firefighter_Result],
                 backgroundColor: ['#007bff', '#dc3545'],
               }],
           },
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: I did all of your suggestions and just declared the Firefighter_Result; to make it a global variable and accessible anywhere in the code. How can I fix it?

Comment: Here's my new output of json_encode from Users_Retrieval.php: {"reporter":5,"firefighter":1}

Comment: @Denzell try taking your `var myPieChart = new Chart` inside the ajax.success function, this way the code will execute only after he has the values. also - please note that you should only make one of the changes I suggested in the first part

Comment: I tried the code you suggested above but it does not display the entire pie chart?

Comment: "the entire pie chart"? what does that mean?

Comment: oh, it might be because the `var myPieChart` definition inside the callback, add `var myPieChart;` to the the var declaration part and inside the code use only `myPieChart` (without the var prefix)

Comment: okay, your JS suggest you've changed to `text(User[0]);` but your comments suggest you've switched to `$JSON_Response['reporter']` there is an 
**OR** between those options, do not do both. use my sample code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183070/discussion-between-denzell-and-jameson-the-dog).